# boost c++ binary tree with hooks to let me know when/where a node is inserted or moved

Tags: c++, boost, tree, binary-search-tree

I've implemented myself an Interval Tree similar but not the same as in [this article.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/). Like the article I've used a simple non self balancing binary tree. I'd like to use something like a red-black tree to keep look-ups efficient.

However an interval tree maintains extra metadata per node such as the maximum and minimum of all intervals of all sub-trees. This means that on any tree manipulation such as insert/remove/re-balancing these values need to be recalculated.

To simplify my concept imagine I had a tree node like below ( not the same as for an interval tree but the concept is similar )

```
struct Node {
    double value; // the value the tree is partitioned on
    Node * left;
    Node * right;
    double max; // max of all values in right subtree
    double min; // min of all values in left subtree
}
```

each node contains a value and a pointer to the left and right. However the node also contains a computation of the max value of the right sub tree and a computation of the min value of the left sub tree. So I might start with an unbalanced tree like

```
                    A(10,8,10)
                  /
            B(9,8,9)               
         /
    D(8,8,8)
```

where the tuple represent **name(value,min,max)**. After re balancing via whatever algorithm the tree uses I would end up with

```
                  B(9,8,10)
               /            \
    D(8,8,8)                  A(10,10,10)
```

However you notice the meta data is now updated. I would need some hooks in the tree code to allow me to efficiently recalculate these values for sub trees that change.

If somebody could show how to use a boost c++ red-black tree or another self balancing tree to do the above simple structure then I am sure I could extended it to my more complex interval tree code.

An attempt has been made to do this with boost::intrusive but it will not really work.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ec5d00968532035

This is because the available hooks provide no guarantees on the state of the tree when the call is made, thus trying to navigate the tree at this point is equivalent to a race condition in multithreaded code. Anything might happen.

```
#include <boost/intrusive/rbtree_algorithms.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

namespace Foo {
    template <typename T>
    struct TNode
    {
       TNode(T i = T())
          :  left(nullptr)
           , right(nullptr)
           , color(0)
           , value(i)
           , min(value)
           , max(value)
       {}
       TNode *parent, *left, *right;
       int      color;
       int      value;
       int      min;
       int      max;
    };

    //Define our own rbtree_node_traits
    template <typename T>
    struct my_rbtree_node_traits
    {
       typedef TNode<T>                                   node;
       typedef TNode<T> *                                 node_ptr;
       typedef const TNode<T> *                           const_node_ptr;
       typedef int                                        color;
       static node_ptr get_parent(const_node_ptr n)       {  return n->parent;   }
       static void set_parent(node_ptr n, node_ptr parent){  n->parent = parent; }
       static node_ptr get_left(const_node_ptr n)         {  return n->left;     }
       static void set_left(node_ptr n, node_ptr left)    
       {  
           n->left = left;     
           bubbleMinMax(n);
       }
       static node_ptr get_right(const_node_ptr n)        {  return n->right;    }
       static void set_right(node_ptr n, node_ptr right)  
       {  
           n->right = right;
           bubbleMinMax(n);
       }
       static color get_color(const_node_ptr n)           {  return n->color;    }
       static void set_color(node_ptr n, color c)         {  n->color = c;       }
       static color black()                               {  return color(0);     }
       static color red()                                 {  return color(1);     }

       static void bubbleMinMax(node_ptr n)
       {
           if(n==nullptr)
               return;
           typedef boost::intrusive::rbtree_algorithms<my_rbtree_node_traits<T>> algo;
           auto parent = n;
           while(parent!=nullptr&&!algo::is_header(parent))
           {
               if(parent->left)
                   parent->min = std::min(parent->left->min, parent->value);
               else
                   parent->min = parent->value;

               if(parent->right)
                   parent->max = std::max(parent->right->max, parent->value);
               else
                   parent->max = parent->value;

               if(parent->parent == parent)
                   break;
               parent = parent->parent;
           }
       }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct node_ptr_compare
    {
       bool operator()(const TNode<T> *a, const TNode<T> *b)
       {  return a->value < b->value;  }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Traits{
        typedef TNode<T> Node;
        typedef my_rbtree_node_traits<T> RbTraits;
        typedef node_ptr_compare<T> Compare;

        static
        void Print(Node const& root, int n = 0)
        {
            std::stack<std::tuple<Node const *,int,char>> stack;
            stack.push(std::make_tuple(&root, 0, 'R'));

            while(!stack.empty())
            {
                auto item = stack.top();
                auto tree = std::get<0>(item);
                auto depth = std::get<1>(item);
                auto dir = std::get<2>(item);
                stack.pop();
                if(tree == nullptr)
                {
                    std::cerr << std::string(depth * 2, ' ') << dir << "-" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << std::string(depth * 2, ' ') << dir << " "
                              << "value: " << tree-> value 
                              << " min: " << tree-> min 
                              << " max: " << tree->max
                              << std::endl;
                    stack.push(std::make_tuple(tree->right, depth + 1,'R'));
                    stack.push(std::make_tuple(tree->left, depth + 1,'L'));
                }
            }
        }
    };
}



int  main()
{
    typedef Foo::Traits<int> Traits;
    typedef boost::intrusive::rbtree_algorithms<Traits::RbTraits> algo;
    Traits::Node header, two(2), three(3);

    // Create an empty rbtree container:
    //"header" will be the header node of the tree
    algo::init_header(&header);

    for(int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
        algo::insert_equal_upper_bound(&header, new Traits::Node(i), Traits::Compare());
    }

    Traits::Print(*algo::root_node(&header));


}
```

and the output is

```
  L value: 1 min: 0 max: 7
    L value: 0 min: 0 max: 0
      L-
      R-
    R value: 2 min: 2 max: 2
      L-
      R-
  R value: 5 min: 4 max: 7
    L value: 4 min: 4 max: 4
      L-
      R-
    R value: 6 min: 6 max: 7
      L-
      R value: 7 min: 7 max: 7
        L-
        R-
```

which is clearly wrong. The first left node has a max of 7 in its subtree but there are no nodes there with a value of 7.

Comment: "I would need some hooks in the tree code to allow me to efficiently recalculate these values for sub trees that change." Please explalin in more detail. In which situation do you want info? What info do you want? Where do you want that info? Maybe as a call to a function? As a log?

Comment: You only show a struct. Are you aware of classes, which contain the methods for manipulating them? If you encapsulate, you can simply add/call your hooks in any situation, with any desired info. Just do not allow any non-class code to manipulate and you are in full control. I.e. make all class attributes protected or even private. This is one of the major differences between C++ and C, I just mention, because the shown code might mean you are thinking in C.

Comment: @Yunnosch You need to imagine that most stl containers are only templated on the data type and the comparison type. They don't give you any info about the tree structure.

Comment: I've just found https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/intrusive/node_algorithms.html. This might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: The boost intrusive containers MAY be what you are looking for. You will certainly be able to hook into when the children change. You'll have to read up about the order of node operations when a re-balance happens to ensure you get your ranges right.

Comment: Yeah I see there is no callback to say that a transaction is complete. If I just naively use **set_left** and **set_right** then I could find the subtree that is set is not valid at that point. Is that the concern?

Comment: Maybe the trick is just to cache the min and max at every level in the tree and mark it as dirty if a **set_left** and **set_right** occurs.  Then the next time a call to **get_min** or **get_max** occurs this will only occur with a valid tree and the cache will be rebuilt for all levels.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, this may not be a problem. I think you should actually give it a crack. All you need to change when you **set_left** is the min, and all you need to change when you **set_right** is the max... I think you may be fine?

Comment: It might work. However whenever a lower level changes the the changed min and max values must bubble up to the root node. Which means either I bubble up a dirty flag and recalculate recursively when asked, clearing the dirty flag as I decend or I bubble up the actual calculated values. The difference between the two solutions is probably not much. But I'll have a hack at it. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It's really not nice. During the callbacks the tree is in a poor state. For example I've found that during set_parent the tree is not valid. That is parent->parent->parent can end up in a loop so it's not possible to ascend the tree. https://i.imgur.com/FjgzKDG.png

Comment: There is an example on coliru showing what happens. The results are wrong and I think it is just because the tree is in a bad state during set_left and set_right so that when I bubble up the min and max values I find the tree disconnected or something worse so the values don't always propogate but sometimes they do.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ec5d00968532035

Comment: I've updated the question with the example so far.

Comment: The solution is to use https://github.com/tinloaf/ygg but it's C++14 and I'm stuck on 11

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how robust this is for a variety of reasons but it appears to work.

```
#include <boost/intrusive/rbtree_algorithms.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

namespace Foo {
    template <typename T>
    struct TNode
    {
       TNode(T i = T())    
          :  parent(nullptr)
           , left(nullptr)
           , right(nullptr)        
           , color(0)
           , value(i)
           , min(value)
           , max(value)

       {}
       TNode *parent, *left, *right;
       int      color;
       int      value;
       int      min;
       int      max;
    };

    //Define our own rbtree_node_traits
    template <typename T>
    struct my_rbtree_node_traits
    {
       typedef TNode<T>                                   node;
       typedef TNode<T> *                                 node_ptr;
       typedef const TNode<T> *                           const_node_ptr;
       typedef int                                        color;
       static node_ptr get_parent(const_node_ptr n)       {  return n->parent;   }
       static void set_parent(node_ptr n, node_ptr parent){  n->parent = parent; }
       static node_ptr get_left(const_node_ptr n)         {  return n->left;     }
       static void set_left(node_ptr n, node_ptr left)    
       {  
           n->left = left;     
           bubbleMinMax(n);
       }
       static node_ptr get_right(const_node_ptr n)        {  return n->right;    }
       static void set_right(node_ptr n, node_ptr right)  
       {  
           n->right = right;
           bubbleMinMax(n);
       }
       static color get_color(const_node_ptr n)           {  return n->color;    }
       static void set_color(node_ptr n, color c)         {  n->color = c;       }
       static color black()                               {  return color(0);     }
       static color red()                                 {  return color(1);     }

       static void bubbleMinMax(node_ptr n)
       {
           if(n==nullptr)
               return;
           auto parent = n;
           typedef boost::intrusive::rbtree_algorithms<my_rbtree_node_traits<T>> algo;
           if(algo::is_header(parent))
           {
               if(parent->left)
                   parent->min = std::min(parent->left->min, parent->value);
               else
                   parent->min = parent->value;

               if(parent->right)
                   parent->max = std::max(parent->right->max, parent->value);
               else
                   parent->max = parent->value;
           }
           else
           {           
               if(parent->left)
                   parent->min = std::min(parent->left->min, parent->value);
               else
                   parent->min = parent->value;

               if(parent->right)
                   parent->max = std::max(parent->right->max, parent->value);
               else
                   parent->max = parent->value;

               bubbleMinMax(parent->parent);           
           }
       }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct node_ptr_compare
    {
       bool operator()(const TNode<T> *a, const TNode<T> *b)
       {  return a->value < b->value;  }
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Traits{
        typedef TNode<T> Node;
        typedef my_rbtree_node_traits<T> RbTraits;
        typedef node_ptr_compare<T> Compare;

        static
        void Print(Node const& root, int n = 0)
        {
            std::stack<std::tuple<Node const *,int,char>> stack;
            stack.push(std::make_tuple(&root, 0, 'R'));

            while(!stack.empty())
            {
                auto item = stack.top();
                auto tree = std::get<0>(item);
                auto depth = std::get<1>(item);
                auto dir = std::get<2>(item);
                stack.pop();
                if(tree == nullptr)
                {
                    std::cerr << std::string(depth * 2, ' ') << dir << "-" << std::endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << std::string(depth * 2, ' ') << dir << " "
                              << "value: " << tree-> value 
                              << " min: " << tree-> min 
                              << " max: " << tree->max
                              << std::endl;
                    stack.push(std::make_tuple(tree->right, depth + 1,'R'));
                    stack.push(std::make_tuple(tree->left, depth + 1,'L'));
                }
            }
        }
    };
}



int  main()
{
    typedef Foo::Traits<int> Traits;
    typedef boost::intrusive::rbtree_algorithms<Traits::RbTraits> algo;
    Traits::Node header, two(2), three(3);

    // Create an empty rbtree container:
    //"header" will be the header node of the tree
    algo::init_header(&header);

    for(int i = 0; i < 16 ; i++){
        algo::insert_equal_upper_bound(&header, new Traits::Node(i), Traits::Compare());
    }

    Traits::Print(*algo::root_node(&header));


}
```

output is

```
R value: 3 min: 0 max: 15
  L value: 1 min: 0 max: 2
    L value: 0 min: 0 max: 0
      L-
      R-
    R value: 2 min: 2 max: 2
      L-
      R-
  R value: 7 min: 4 max: 15
    L value: 5 min: 4 max: 6
      L value: 4 min: 4 max: 4
        L-
        R-
      R value: 6 min: 6 max: 6
        L-
        R-
    R value: 11 min: 8 max: 15
      L value: 9 min: 8 max: 10
        L value: 8 min: 8 max: 8
          L-
          R-
        R value: 10 min: 10 max: 10
          L-
          R-
      R value: 13 min: 12 max: 15
        L value: 12 min: 12 max: 12
          L-
          R-
        R value: 14 min: 14 max: 15
          L-
          R value: 15 min: 15 max: 15
            L-
            R-
```